# Find max value of a column in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The problem started because I have a table (Clientes), in which the primary key is not auto-incremental. I want to select the max value stored in a column database.

Like this select, but with eloquent ORM (Laravel):

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Clientes
```

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
Cliente::with('id')->max(id);
Cliente::select('id')->max(id);
```

I prefer not to make a simple raw `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Clientes`

I cannot make it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Cliente::max('id')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 51):

Laravel makes this very easy, in your case you would use

```
$maxValue = Cliente::max('id');
```

But you can also retrieve the newest record from the table, which will be the highest value as well

```
$newestCliente = Cliente::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first(); // gets the whole row
$maxValue = $newestCliente->id;
```

or for just the value

```
$maxValue = Cliente::orderBy('id', 'desc')->value('id'); // gets only the id
```

Or, if you have a `created_at` column with the date you could get the value like this

```
$maxValue = Cliente::latest()->value('id');
```

Relevant Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 13):

```
    $maxValue = DB::table('Clientes')->max('id');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Cliente::where('column_name', $your_Valu)->max('id') // You get any max column
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Additionally, explain why there is a `where` condition in your code

Comment: Finally, doesn't work since you filter it down to a single column for count.

Comment: Where condition is optional. you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following code :

```
 $min_id = DB::table('table_name')->max('id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates